# Colordict dictionary use

Tags: applications, dictionary

I have Colordict 4.4.6 installed on an Android 8, so far everything seems fine, I've also installed 3 dictionaries, but Colordict seems to work only with 1 dictionary at time, I can use the up button to position the dictionary that I want to use, but the apps seems not be able to check meanings in multiple dictionaries (I was used to Goldendict, which can work/show multiple dictionaries). Am I missing something here?